# Software for computing heat of formation

Tags: computational-chemistry, software-recommendations

What are the the options available for software to compute heat of formation ($\Delta_f H$) of a given compound in your own system? (Preferably at no cost, like GAMESS.)

Comment: I think GAMESS already has some composite methods like G3MP2 which can estimate heats of formation

Answer (score 2):

[Gaussian](https://gaussian.com/) and [ORCA](https://hpc.hku.hk/hpc/software/orca/) can calculate the heat as well as free energies of formation of a given system.

Comment: ORCA looks actually like a nice solution, easy to setup and run, and enthalpy can be computed as easy as [this](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/prop/thermo.html), but how to compute heat of formation?